# Changing format from input default to Month D, YYYY

Tags: java, date, for-loop, format, date-formatting

0

I'm making a Date class for my school work which basically do some basic features just like API Date. Non of the methods are allowed to associate with the API Date class of Java except for one of the constructors which set to current local time. Then I made a method to change format based on input option. The code work pretty good however there's a miscalculate in month output for the format method. Perhaps I did the logic on the array wrong but could't figure out how to make it right.
For example: if I put 4/2/2019 and choose option B then it'd print "December 2 2019" instead of "April"

I tried month = 0 and 1 for the loop it dont work out.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Date
{
    // declare needed variables
   private int day;
   private int month;
   private int year;

   /**
    * Default constructor to set the date info to the current date 
    */
   public Date()
   {
       // I have trouble assign Date using the Java API Date class
       Date d1 = new Date();
       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       cal.setTime(d1);
       day= cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
       month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
       year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    }
    /**
    * Overloaded constructor to set the date info based on user input
    * @param int inMonth to input month value
    * @param int inDay to input day value
    * @param int inYear to input year value
    *
    */
    public Date( int inMonth, int inDay, int inYear)
    {
       //set all the inputs into suitable variables
       day = inDay;
       month = inMonth;
       year = inYear;
    }
    public String getDate(char format)
    {
        //String Array for option B

        String[] mArray = {"January","Febuary","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"};
        String dayString = new String();
        //Switch code with param input format option and return the String based on it
        switch(format)
        {
            case 'A':
                dayString = month+"/"+day+"/"+year;
            break;
            case 'B':
            for(month = 1;month<mArray.length;month++)
            {

                dayString = mArray[month]+" "+day+" "+year;
            }
            break;
        }
        return dayString;
    }
    /**
    * ToString method to return date info
    * @return String of Date
    */
     public String toString()
    {
        //Return value of Date in String
        return month+"/"+day+"/"+year;
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is the code you have for option B:

```
        for(month = 1;month<mArray.length;month++)
        {

            dayString = mArray[month]+" "+day+" "+year;
        }
```

This iterates through the months from 1 through 11. So first time through the loop is assigns `February 2 2019`, next time this value is overwritten with `March 2 2019`, etc. After the loop the last value assigned, `December 2 2019`, stays there.

There is no point in using a loop. The basic fix of your problem is to leave it out:

```
        dayString = mArray[month] + " " + day + " " + year;
```

Assuming your months are numbered from 1 for January through 12 for December, you are not getting the exact correct array element, but you’ll find out soon enough, so I am leaving it to yourself to fix it. In any case you need a clear decision: Is January represented as 0 or 1 inside your class?

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55490086/642706) looks good to me. I'll add a couple thoughts: class name, and *java.time*.

## Class naming

Mixing your own class named `Date` with an existing class `Date` is asking for trouble. Use another name.

## *java.time*

Replace this:

```
   // I have trouble assign Date using the Java API Date class
   Date d1 = new Date();
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal.setTime(d1);
   day= cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
   month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
   year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

…with modern *java.time* classes.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault(java.util.TimeZone)) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument. If critical, confirm the zone with your user.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the code becomes ambiguous to read in that we do not know for certain if you intended to use the default or if you, like so many programmers, were unaware of the issue.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Back to your code.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;  // If crucial, confirm with the user.
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
this.day = today.getDayOfMonth() ;
this.month = today.getMonthValue() ; // Sanely numbered 1-12 for January-December. Tip: better to use the `Month` enum objects rather than mere integer.
this.year = today.getYear() ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).